# flask API how to avoid user concurrency in a function

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a backend API in flask and I have a feature in which a user can take an action for him by clicking on a button. That send a call a function to attribute the action to him with several checks:

```
def accept_action(id, user) -> bool:
    """
        Accept the action

        Args :
            id : action id
            user : user who accepts
    """
    if is_valid_id(id):
        action = mongo.db.actions.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})

        if action['state'] != 'not_assigned':
            raise Error(NOT_ASSIGNED_STATE)

        # lot of checks about the capacity of the user
        ...
        # several updates on action OBJECT
        ...

        mongo.db.actions.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)},{'$set': action})

        # Notification for all needed users
        ...

        return True
    raise Error(INVALID_ID)
```

The issue I have is if two user click at the same time. The second call do the find_one before the ending of the first call (util the update_one), so the original action isn't finalized and the second call pass all checks. At the end, these two users take this action when it should be only one and the second one will be blockedwhen he submits.

I thought about transaction but it just do all actions and validate them at the end, it didn't manage concurrency. the best functionality is that the second call wait about the end of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global `threading.Lock` object and use it as context manager to ensure that only one thread within this particular Python interpreter is inside a given code block at any time.

```
import threading

DB_LOCK = threading.Lock()

def accept_action(id, user) -> bool:
    if is_valid_id(id):
        with DB_LOCK:
            action = mongo.db.actions.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})
            ...
            mongo.db.actions.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)},{'$set': action})

        # Notification for all needed users
        ...
```

Since Flask uses threadpools for requests, only one request will be inside the `with` block at any time (lock is aquired when entering the block and released when leaving).

Note: If you need lots of these "critical sections", it might make sense to make global `Lock()` factory:

```
LOCKS = {}
def get_lock(name):
    lock = LOCKS.get(name, None)
    if not lock:
        lock = threading.Lock()
        LOCKS[name] = lock
    return lock
```

Then you can use granular locks like this:

```
with get_lock('user_update'):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks @vaizki, it's typically what I need. Thanks again

Comment: Note that this of course works only inside a single Python interpreter / process. So if you have multiple processes, virtual machines etc, this will not block concurrent access from them.